# Compute thickness of branches in a 2D image

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing

I would like to ask for suggestions on how to obtain the thickness of the edges in a given input image

Input image:

[image]

I tried to follow the commands given in a similar question posted, [How to determine edgeweights from width of skeleton using MorphologicalGraph (or workaround)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/how-to-determine-edgeweights-from-width-of-skeleton-using-morphologicalgraph-or?rq=1)

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww0td.png"]
g = MorphologicalGraph[img, EdgeWeight -> Automatic];
weights = OptionValue[Options[g, EdgeWeight], EdgeWeight]
vertices = VertexList[g];
crds = OptionValue[Options[g, VertexCoordinates], VertexCoordinates];
edges = List @@@ EdgeList[g];

GraphPlot[Rule @@@ edges,
  VertexCoordinates -> Thread[vertices -> crds],
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> (With[{w = 
        Pick[Rescale[weights], edges, (#2 | Reverse[#2])][[1]]},
      {Thickness[.02 (.1 + w)],
       ColorData["SunsetColors"][.9 w], Line[#1]}] &), 
  AspectRatio -> 1]
```

However, the output is the following:

[image]

I'm not sure how to proceed. Any suggestions will be really helpful.
In the output I would like to obtain the thickness of edge and corresponding edge indices.

Source of image: [ref](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29262374)

Also sharing the link of crosspost [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1953645).

Comment: Could you please let us know where your source image is from? It is very familiar.

Comment: I am sure someone will post an answer that will work for at least this sample image, but when I needed to do this last time, I gave up on Mathematica and used Fiji instead, which is able to extract the pixel intensities for each segment. We can use something like `SkeletonTransform` or `DistanceTransform` to convert thickness into intensity. For this reason, I did suggest to Wolfram to make MorphologicalGraph capable not only of recording the number of pixels in each segment, but also the pixel intensities.

Comment: maybe the following could be staring point? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192177/automated-calculation-of-tree-branches-radius-from-thinned-image/192319#192319

Comment: The idea with SkeletonTransform is something like this: `ImageAdjust@Pruning@Pruning@SkeletonTransform[img]`. This way thicknesses are changed to intensities. One problem is that `SkeletonTransform` does not produce the same kind of skeleton as `Thinning`, which would be much nicer (fewer "outgrowths")

Comment: Yet another reason why I suggest NOT using Mathematica's `MorphologicalGraph` is that  it does not support multigraphs. Your image has multi-edges, which seem important here. I would want to retain them.

Comment: This is the tool in Fiji: https://imagej.net/AnalyzeSkeleton And something similar to your application was why I tried to much to use Fiji directly from Mathematica (but then gave up on that too). https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180513/12

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1953645).

Comment: When cross-posting, please always links the posts together, so people won't spend time doing the same thing twice.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you, I will try Fiji. Links have been updated.